# move member group after order completes

Tags: expresso-store, checkout, orders, stripe

I've just been building a small commerce site using Store and Stripe.

It's all working pretty sweetly but I need to know if there's a way I can move the member to another group once their order has been placed successfully.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derek hit the nail on the head - there is no way to do this automatically, so you will need to create a simple PHP extension to update the member's group in the database.

If you're not sure where to start, take a look at the [EE Extension Development Guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html), and you want to use the `store_order_complete_end` hook.

Comment: Steven - Did you end up doing this and do you have an extension you created to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [store_order_complete_end](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/extension_hooks.html#store_order_complete_end) extension hook. The `$order` array should contain the `member_id` of the customer, which you can then use in a query to change their member group assignment.